# Awaiting Reviewer Selection AFTER Awaiting Reviewer Scores?

Tags: online-publication

I submitted a manuscript to BMJ Open about a month ago and have checked status every day. The status changed from "Awaiting Reviewer Reply" to "Awaiting Reviewer Scores", then stayed like that for a couple of weeks and now today the status is "Awaiting Reviewer Selection". Is this not backwards?

Thank you, Sara

Comment: Ask the editor.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Please have a look at [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/7734), which should answer your question. If it doesn’t, please [edit] it to clarify.

Comment: @astronat I think it doesn't. This question is about a deviation from the typical workflow.

Comment: As per Solar Mike, email the editorial team in the first instance to ask for an update. Most journals will email back and tell you what stage it's at and answer any specific questions.

Comment: Tangential comment about "have checked status every day": Relax. This is not good for your blood pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's backwards.

Most likely the assigned reviewer agreed to review but then didn't provide a review, declined to review, or provided a review that made the editor think another review is required. Therefore, new reviewers are being invited.